# How to query the int64 filed with between and in Go/gorm?

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

I am new to `Go`, is there any one who knows how to query the int64 filed with between and in Go/gorm?

I would like to use below sql `select * from porject where created_at between ? and ?;`, but I don't know how to do it? thanks so much for any advice.

```
type Project struct {
    Id        int64  `json:"id" gorm:"primary_key;AUTO_INCREMENT;comment:'id'"`
    Email  string `json:"email" gorm:"type:varchar(255);comment:'email'"`
    CreatedAt int64 `json:"created_at" gorm:"type:bigint(20);comment:'created_time'"`
}


func (p *Project) ProjectList(pageInfo cts.PageInfo) ([]Project, int, error) {

    if p.Email != "" {
        db = db.Where("email like ?", "%"+p.Email+"%")
    }
    if p.CreatedAt != 0 {
        db = db.Where("created_at <> ?", p.CreatedAt)
    }
    err1 := db.Offset((pageInfo.Page - 1) * pageInfo.PageSize).Limit(pageInfo.PageSize).Order("id desc").Find(&List).Error
    
    db.Count(&total)
    
    return List, total, err1
}
```

I need to pass front end to query data by below json

```
{
  "page": 1,
  "page_size": 20,
  "email":"test@test",
  "create_at_st": 1654176767,
  "create_at_end": 1654896767
}
```

or

```
{
  "page": 1,
  "page_size": 20,
  "email":"test@test",
  "create_at": ['1654176767','1654896767']
}
```

or other json, as long as it can achieve the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your query ,assuming you have `s.CreatedAtMin` and `s.CreatedAtMax` with you .Then you can have something like

> db.Where("created_at between ? and ?", min, max)

```
func (p *Project) ProjectList(pageInfo cts.PageInfo) ([]Project, int, error) {

    if p.Email != "" {
        db = db.Where("email like ?", "%"+s.Email+"%")
    }
    if p.CreatedAt != 0 {
        //db = db.Where("created_at <> ?", s.CreatedAt)
        db.Where("created_at between ? and ?", s.CreatedAtMin, s.CreatedAtMax)
    }
    err1 := db.Offset((pageInfo.Page - 1) * pageInfo.PageSize).Limit(pageInfo.PageSize).Order("id desc").Find(&List).Error
    
    db.Count(&total)
    
    return List, total, err1
}
```

Comment: I am sorry, wrong word, not `s.` but `p.`, there is no filed of `CreatedAtMin` and `CreatedAtMax` in Project struct.

Comment: then you can pass them as function arguments